# spree + ror + passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

Not able access site on local

I would like to know if I am doing something wrong
Because I only see It works page even if I point to public folder of my site

My apache2.conf

```
  LoadModule passenger_module /home/harssh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /home/harssh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19
   PassengerRuby /home/harssh/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby   

PassengerMaxPoolSize 15
PassengerPoolIdleTime 10


<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName spree
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /home/harssh/Documents/spreebackup/mystore/public   
      RailsEnv development
      <Directory /home/harssh/Documents/spreebackup/mystore/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
       PassengerMinInstances 5

   </VirtualHost>
```

My error log file content

> [Wed Mar 20 12:09:19 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) configured
>   -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Mar 20 12:20:08 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Wed Mar 20 12:20:12 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Mar 20 12:20:21 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
>
> [Wed Mar 20 12:22:50 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Wed Mar 20 12:24:50 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:36:42 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:36:47 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:46:26 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:46:51 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:46:58 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
>   Phusion_Passenger/3.0.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Wed Mar 20 14:47:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not
>   exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

And when I browse localhost it shows only It works page

Comment: Where question? What tried?

Comment: I would like to know if I am doing something wrong
Because I only get It works page even if I point to public folder of my site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution

I had to add Listen 1025

and add port in place of 80

and it worked dont know why still.........